# Android - local image in online page

Tags: android, webview, local, offline

I am working on a fullscreen webapp to androidPage Not Found We couldn't find the page you requested. I have everything done but can I possible add all the images offline in the app and the html online?

I am using:We did, webView.loadUrl("http://site.com/Sd34DsX.html");

And I wonder if i could host the images in the HTML file like this:

```
#fotball
    background-image: url('file:///android_asset/fotball.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    float: left;
    position:fixed
```

Answer (score 0):

almost, but no, because you can't write to the asset folder from within the app. you only use that to store resources which your app will use after compiling.

what you can do is get the entire HTML as a string, and do a string search for all of the image paths. You can then retrieve those images in their own http requests, and save them to a folder in external storage.

you can then modify your html string to replace all of the image paths with local paths.

your webview can use string data as a webpage.

Comment: If you went this route, you may have to also download any javascript files and css style files that are linked within the html file, to make it work/look like the original.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
background-image: url('file:///android_asset/fotball.png');
```

[try a data url](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/), which has no cross-domain restriction:

```
background-image: url('data:image/format;base64,IMAGEDATA');
```

Comment: The linked page provides an example, "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub/
/ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcpp
V0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7" is used instead of a url.